# How to use response field in a new request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have this issue that I want to solve.
I want to create a new http request using field from previous response

1. I send a request
2. I used Json  extractor to move the response string to a variable (let call this string nurl)
3. I used Regular expression and move the field that I want to "Reference Name"
   (meanning from nurl I just want tt_cid)

Now I want to make a new call, and use that field tt_cid in my new call

How I shall call tt_cid? since it is not passed as User Defined Variables, 
when I use tt_cid, I do not think J meter know it, since it is not written there, I just pulled it from the response.

Provided a Pic of what I have done
Regards to you all

[image: Response]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer call it `${tt_cid}`.

> since it is not passed as User Defined Variables, when I use tt_cid,
>   I do not think J meter know it,

For your understanding add `Debug Sampler` after Regular expression,

You will see all your JMeter variables, including `tt_cid`, which can be called as other variables `${tt_cid}` inside other Samplers.

It's called `Reference Name` and not `Variable Name` because it's more complicated, You should read JMeter's [Regular Expression](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) to understand how it works internally, But basically it saves more than just 1 Variable.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding I will read it, but can anyone help on how to move Reference Name to a new Http request?

Comment: Use it ` ${tt_cid} `